# jquery array.push() goes wrong

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two array which are temp and final;
When I on click a file type input, input.files will push into temp, then if i press confirm button: 
1) final will equal to temp,
2) temp = []
Now, final has temp object, and temp will be a empty array.

However, when temp.push(input.files) happen, final array will be push at the same time,
Just a demo below,any possible reason(s) makes result push into final?:

```
var temp = [];
var final = [];

temp = final;
$(document).on('click',function(evt){
  var currentTarget = $(evt.currentTarget);
  var result = currentTarget[0].files;
   for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
     temp.push(result);                //when result push to temp,it push to final also
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.confirmButton', function () {
  final = temp;
  temp = [];
});
```

Comment: Your third line of code is setting temp equal to final.  They both point to the same array at that point.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the reply, I really need temp equal to final to init some event, any other way to rewrite this code?

Comment: Can you explain why you *need* them to start off the same for init?

Comment: You're also declaring a variable called `final`. Final is a reserved word and should not be used to declare vars.

Comment: @Taplar well,I just want temp[]  equal to final [] at the beginning, then final [] gonna change only after confirmButton is clicked.

Comment: @bastos.sergio Thanks for reply, should I do push()? or anything else?

Comment: So I guess I have to ask what you mean by "equality", because setting them both to an empty array at the start, does make them equal, but not the same.

Comment: @Taplar Ok, there's a pop up, fileupload input is inside, I open this pop up and then upload file, result[x] will push into temp[ ], final[ ] still empty, after confirmBtn, final[ ] will get the temp[ ] objects/values, ,temp[ ] will be empty and popup will br close, now i click popup again, I want temp[ ] have the objects/values from final [ ], that's what i call temp equal to final

Comment: Then you do not want them to be the same on init.  You want to set them to be the same when the pop up opens.

Comment: @Taplar Yup,so should I push final[ ] to temp[ ] and on click confirmBtn ,temp.length = 0 to clear up temp[ ],In additional, how to do the push final[ ] to temp[ ],cuz I try temp.push(final),it doesn’t seem right

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use the `Final` keyword as a variable, this is the `reserved keyword` for the language.
2. In the third statement, you have referenced the `final` variable to `temp` so any update in each will point to the same data.

Ideally, your code should be like:

```js
var temp = [];
var finalData = [];
$("#fileUploaded").on('change', function(evt) {
  var currentTarget = $(evt.currentTarget);
  var result = currentTarget[0].files;
  for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
    temp.push(result);
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.confirmButton', function () {
  finalData = temp;
  temp = [];
  console.log(finalData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple id="fileUploaded" />

<button class="confirmButton">confirm</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!